# Page focus necessary for Bootstrap form?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, submit

I have a form on a Bootstrap webpage with a single textarea and submit button.  When you click the button, whatever is in the textarea is supposed to be added to a div.

Everything on the page works except for one thing, you have to click on a menu item or something (something to add a # at the end of the URL) in order for it to work, otherwise the page just refreshes.

What does this mean?  Is there an easy fix?

Comment: Why don't you post some the code you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing some code I can't be sure, but you are probably not stopping the default Submit event on the form. You need to either use `return false;` or `event.preventDefault()` in your submit function.

Here is an example:

```
<form id="doitform">
    <input type="text" id="textvalue"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Do it" id="doitbutton" />
</form>

<div id="contenthere">

</div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
          $('form').submit(function (event) {
            $('#contenthere').append("<div>" + $('#textvalue').val() + "</div>");
              return false;
          });
      });

</script>
```

This is binding a new submit event to the form and preventing the form submit by returning false (after it has done what we want it to do).